# Cannot read an HDF file when using xlwings - HDFStore Requires PyTables

Tags: python, pandas, pytables, xlwings

I am trying to create various Excel UDFs in python by using xlwings. My UDFs rely on values that are pulled from an HDF file. However, every time I click the "Import Functions" button in Excel, I receive an error. Below is an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw

matrix1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size = (1000, 1000)))
matrix2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size = (1000, 100)))

matrix1.to_hdf('matrix.h5', key = 'mat1', mode = 'w')
matrix2.to_hdf('matrix.h5', key = 'mat2', mode = 'a')

arg = pd.read_hdf('matrix.h5', key = 'mat2', mode = 'r')

@xw.func
def dummy(x, y):
   return 17
```

When I click on the "Import Functions" button in the xlwings ribbon in Excel, I receive the following

[image: Error Message]

If I try to run the program with Spyder, I have no issues and can generate the HDF files just fine.

Interestingly, if I remove the lines where I write the HDF file, and just leave the one where I read it, I get an error saying

```
FileNotFoundError: File matrix.h5 does not exist ...
```

Even though I have confirmed that the file does exist. If I run the same code in Spyder, I have no issues, it works fine.

Is there some kind of compatibility issue with xlwings and HDF files, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see xlwings being used for anything in the examples. It is however true that the PyTables is required. Try running `pip install tables` to install it.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the problem. When I run `pip install tables` I get some lines saying `Requirement already satisfied` which leads me to believe that it is already installed.  I have no problem running the files within my IDE, but when I try to load the functions into Excel via "Import Functions", I get the error.